# How can I integrate marklogic with single sign on?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos, marklogic

I have requirement to setup single sign on for my MarkLogic server. What are the steps that I need to perform for doing such task?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `External Security`, which comes in roughly three flavors in MarkLogic:

- Kerberos
- LDAP
- SAML

Kerberos is a ticket-based authentication protocol, so that should work well for Single Sign-on.

SAML is a standard that should also allow Single Sign-on but in a more generic way.

Details about each of those options, including steps on how to setup each is available in the `Security Guide`:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/external-auth#chapter

HTH!

Comment: Hi Grtjn. I was able to successfully implemente authentication via kerberos and authorization via ldap. I was able to create an app server to test this changes and it is working fine. However when I try to integrate the same thing with Qconsole it is giving me error (403 unauthorized). Rest everything is working fine. Can you give me some pointers on this.